# how to set UINavigationController as a rootviewcontroller using xib in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Here I Have tried to set navigationcontroller as a rootviewcontroller but it shows a error. How to solve it.

Extra argument 'bundle' in call.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let nav = UINavigationController()
    let vc = MyNavigationController(nibName: "MyNavigationController", bundle: nil)

    nav.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)

    self.window!.rootViewController = nav
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    nav.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)


    return true
}
```

Comment: any one answer for this error.

Comment: i have solution for this in objective-c ,if you want it than say YEs...

Comment: Yes can u send the solution...@KandhalBhutiya

Comment: okay see my ans. :) @saravanakumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var nav1 = UINavigationController()
var mainView = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) //ViewController = Name of your controller
nav1.viewControllers = [mainView]
self.window!.rootViewController = nav1
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

OR

```
var navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController));
```

Comment: @saravanakumar Try This : var navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController));

Comment: My question is how to set UINavigationcontroller as a rootview controller?

Comment: How to implement sidemenu(slidemenu) using xib in swift language andwithout using third party library...@Bhavesh Nai.

Comment: @saravanakumar Sorry dude no idea about sidemenu in swift

Answer (score 2):

**Take it** its in objective-C

```
 self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        viewcontroller=[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

        UINavigationController *navigation=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller];

        self.window.rootViewController=navigation;
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```